# Возможно ли принимать данные с Websocket на сервере?

Tags: сервер, websocket

Как я понимаю, websocket отправляет данные с сервера лишь в браузер, но если мне нужно постоянно принимать данные через websocket, т.е. с сервера, который их отправляет, на мой, то возможно ли что-то сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Websocket пересылает данные во всех направлениях - и от клиента к серверу, и от сервера к клиенту. Вам на своем сервере просто нужно подключится к сокет-серверу как клиент, и получать данные

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание, что `Websocket` это не либа и не фреймворк, это протокол передачи данных, как `ftp` или `http`. Приложение, которое реализует передажу данных по этому протоколу может быть как клиентом - не только браузер, например мобильные устройства и даже десктоп, так и сервером, соответственно для поключения к серверу Вам необходимо реализовать клиентский код и все заработает.